# Does Gmail accepts embedded Audio files using HTML, not in attachments

Tags: html

So I've been trying to embed an audio file on the mail itself, not in the attachments but when sending it our, gmail removes the audio from the mail

I tried using this code from W3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp
When I try it on my computer, the audio shows but disappears when sent on Gmail

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible.
I tried to do it that way and it did not work. it said "browser does not support the audio tag.", this is a security feature.

[image: This is the image]